# Highlighting table rows only on the first 3 app uses

Tags: objective-c, ios4, rows

I want to highlight -color-my app's new rows when i release a new update or when i add a new row. Also, i want to keep them highlighted only when the user uses my app at least 3 times. How can i do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store in the NSUserDefaults a value for each new table row remembering how many times they've been viewed. Increment a number in the applicationHasFinishedLaunching for each of the rows. If the row's view count is more than 3, remove it.  When rendering look up the row id in the NSUserDefaults and check to see if it should be highlighted.

Adding new rows..

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:myRowId];
```

Rendering..

```
 if ([(NSInteger*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:myRowId] intValue] < 3) { 
  // render highlighted...
 } else {
  // render normal
 }
```